# Install Microsoft Office Proofing tools under Wine

Tags: 14.04, wine, microsoft-office, winetricks

Due to compatibility issues I had to ditch openoffice and libreoffice for Microsoft Office. I installed it using wine and everything works fine so far. The one thing I am missing, though is the Swiss German proofing tool, which is not part of the standard installation.

I downloaded it from the Microsoft website and got a `.exe` file. When I execute it I get the error `The expected version of the product was not found on the system`. I checked the installed version of Microsoft Office, it's 2010, also the proofing tool I downloaded is the service pack 2 for Microsoft Office 2010.

Can anyone help me on this? All the answers I found online were about uninstalling Microsoft Office, adding the files from the service pack to the mounted `.iso` archive, and adding a few lines to some `.xml` files, but these require an archive, whereas I could only find `.exe` files to download.

Comment: Would anyone bother to comment WHY this has been downvoted please? I have done a significant amount of  research and believe this is a valid question to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Office 2010 works fine under Wine as long as you install first "playonlinux" package.

```
Install playonlinux
start playonlinux
install - office - office 2010
```

if you do not have a official version of office 2010 try do download a pre activited version.

This should do it

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My problem is not with office 2010 as such, just that the installer for the proofing tools (extra languages for spell check) will not work. Do you know if that works with playonlinux?